# custom date axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a plot in `ggplot2` with customized ticks. The problem is if I choose e.g. `date_breaks = "5 years"`, the plot will start the labeling at the very last date year, and go back in 5 year intervals, but miss on the first date. This makes sense, but what if I would like to show the first date as well so people see the beginning of my plot? Moreover, the ticks in between are not shown. 
So what I would like to have is:

- 5 year intervals, each labelled (e.g. assume a label at 1988) and also marked on the axis
- 1 year marks not labelled in between (e.g. if we assume 1988 is labelled, 1989 to 1992 should only be marked on the axis with ticks, but not be labelled)
- a custom start date for the labeling and a custom end date for the labeling. Now of course both is likely not possible if numbers are not in the sequence of 5 years. In this case, it probably makes sense to decide for either a custom start/end date and do the labeling from there. Let me know what you think is the best solution in this case.

MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(x = rnorm(29*2),var=c(rep("x1",29),rep("x2",29)),
                   time=rep(seq(as.Date("1983/12/31"),as.Date("2011/12/31"), "year"),2))
library(ggplot2);library(scales)
ggplot(data=test,aes(x=time, y=x, colour=var)) + 
geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y",date_breaks = "5 years",
                             date_minor_breaks="1 year")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just define breaks and labels manually which you can adjust arbitrarily.

```
dts <- as.Date(paste0(seq(1980, 2015, 1), "-01-01"))
x.labs <- substr(as.character(dts), 1, 4)
x.labs[5:length(dts - 2) %% 5 != 0] <- ""  # modulo 5

library(ggplot2);library(scales)
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=time, y=x, colour=var)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks=dts, labels=x.labs)
```

***Yielding***

[image]

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for, ty!

Comment: wait, now it doesn't work anymore. It says `Error: `breaks` and `labels` must have the same length`. Did u change anything? I tried twice with deleting everything else before.

Comment: Ah I see, the issue was that both vectors must have the same length and we need to set the non labels to "". Now seems to work, ty for the update.

Comment: Exactly, `scale_x_date()` needs one label for every break.